# Can I query Hyperledger Fabric ledger or update ledger without chaincode in peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I have simple question about Hyperledger Fabric. so here is my question:

I know that for committing peers (ordinary peers) it's not 100% necessary to have chaincode installed, but every peer should have ledger and that's 100% necessary.

so suppose I am committing peer and I have not chaincode installed, but I have ledger of course. Now new block arrives from ordering peer.

1) I should check blocks validity, so I need to query ledger

2) I should add this block, so I need to update ledger.

So how can I do this two above without chaincode? Isn't chaincode necessary for above operations? (query and update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the transaction/block's validity, the peer does not need to have the chaincode, the readwrite set available in the transaction is compared against the ledger (available in all peer) to decide the validity.

And adding the block to the ledger is not dependent upon the validity check. If it was found invalid, it will still be added to the ledger but with an invalid tag.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my main question. you said: "transaction is compared against the ledger", "will still be added to the ledger", My main question was can I query ledger and update ledger without chaincode?

Comment: The answer to your question is, "yes you can do both query ledger and update ledger". My original response attempts to clarify why the answer is "yes". I see what you are saying, I think I will edit my response above.

Comment: @adnan.c could you do the following exercise l, setup a consortium with two organisations having two peers org1 creates channel with both organisations part of it and org1 install chaincode and push data and try to get the data with out installing chaincode from org2 peers it will through error and it will ask you to install chaincode Try this you will understand

Answer (score 1):

```
You cannot query a peer without having a chaincode. Must need chaincode installed in the peer in order to query | invoke.
```

Hyperledger Fabric has two types of peers
1) Endorsing peers
2) Committing Peers

Endorsing peers must need a chaincode which means you need to install chaincode on endorsing peers because its duty is to make sure the transaction owner has sufficient rights and it simulates that transaction against the ledger for that it needs a chaincode interface in order to complete simulation.

Once the simulation is done it sends back the R/W sets and simulation result to client and client will send this to the orderer

Orderer then distributes to committing peers ( No need to install chaincode)

**Whole**:   Applications generate a transaction proposal which they send to each of the required set of peers for endorsement. Each of these endorsing peers then independently executes a chaincode using the transaction proposal to generate a transaction proposal response. It does not apply this update to the ledger, but rather simply signs it and returns it to the application.